# How can I correctly implement this operation with averaging unsigned chars - C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, floating-point

Consider the following, seemingly simple, problem, that I've come across in solving assignments in CV involving masks and implementing AA in ray tracing.

An color in the RGB format has three channels, each channel represented by an `unsigned char`, hence `0 <= channel value <= 255`. For reasons of symmetry, let's consider a single channel. I want to sum up channel values over a certain set of points, then average and round that (not just truncate) and store back into an `unsigned char`. Note that in all the problems, the resulting averaged value is guaranteed to be in the range `[0, 255]`, it's an invariant of the algorithm.

This looks like an easy task, but I'm concerned with the following:

**p.1**. The most important: *the type choice*, see pseudocode below for which types I need. More precisely, I'm getting a narrowing conversion error, which turns into an error with `-pedantic-errors` set, and I don't want to simply wave it away.

**p.2**. The idea of going from a wider type that can accumulate many `uchar`'s, back to the `uchar` type. I'm confident that the algorithm is guaranteed to produce a value in the `uchar` range, but is it enough? Should I worry about this?

Pseudocode (`cv::Vec3b` is a fixed size 3x1 array of `unsigned char` in OpenCV which iI use for image storing and output):

```
// this returns a value in the range [0, 255]
cv::Vec3b processing_func(const point&) { ... }

accum_type acc_r = 0, acc_g = 0 , acc_b = 0;
for (point p: point_set) {
    const cv::Vec3b color = processing_func(p);
    acc_r += color[0]; acc_g += color[1]; acc_b += color[2];
}
cv::Vec3b result_color{roundf(acc_r / (floating_type)set_size),
                       roundf(acc_g / (floating_type)set_size),
                       roundf(acc_b / (floating_type)set_size)};
// hello narrowing conversion ^^^
```

Refer to **p.1**, what should the `accum_type` and `floating_type` be (the latter required to divide correctly without truncation), or would you maybe code it differently?

Edit after the first comment: `set_size` is an integer above 0, it can be hardcoded if required, but in general is bound to change. It's e.g. AA factor, squared; or mask size, and so on.

Comment: What is `set_size`? A constant? A variable? What type does it have?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'll add that now. It's an integer, always above 0. As far as constant or not, it can be hardcoded as a constant if required. It may e.g. represent mask size or AA factor, squared.

Comment: Sorry, I should have included this in my previous request for clarification: What are expected values (or value ranges) for `set_size`? What are possible candidate types for `accum_type`?

Comment: I think in these problems `set_size` is rather small, i.e. imagine, what size can a filter mask or how large can AA factor in rendering be, it's just that large. `accum_type` anything you come up with, it's free.

Comment: I think a 32 bit int should do, it'll allow you to sum about a billion values.

Comment: @Skizz - I added one more question to your answer as an edit to save space - please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be tempted to use unsigned integers:-

```
uint acc_r = set_size / 2, acc_g = set_size / 2, acc_b = set_size / 2;

for (point p: point_set) {
    const cv::Vec3b color = processing_func(p);
    acc_r += color[0]; acc_g += color[1]; acc_b += color[2];
}

cv::Vec3b result_color{acc_r / set_size, acc_g / set_size, acc_b / set_size}
```

Notice that I initialise the RGB values to 1/2 (set_size / 2) so that the division rounds rather than truncates.

Comment: ..and you'd hit the same narrowing conversion from `float` to `uchar` wouldn't you? :)

Comment: I don't think so, the sum of n chars divided by n will always be a small enough to fit in a char so there's no narrowing. I'm not using floating point anywhere.

Comment: Doesn't `roundf` return a `float? Because I have that code and it produces said N.C.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally left the roundf call in there! Fixing it now.

Comment: Ok, I see now; and the accumulators should be 0 in the beginning, shouldn't they? (I added that to my question, was a mistake, too, not to include that).

Comment: No, I initialise them to effectively a half so the division rounds rather than truncate. Look up fixed point maths for more information on how this works.

Comment: OK, well deserved +1 and reading up on fixed point, would've never come up with that myself. Oh wait `uint` -> `uchar` not a narrowing?

Comment: No, if you think of each value as 0.8 fixed point value in the range 0<=c<1 then add n of them together and then dividing by n will always result in a 0.8 fixed point value. e.g. 255 + 255 = 510, plus 1 for the initial half = 511, divide by 2 = 255 (remainder 1)

Comment: Unfortunately, with `-pedantic`, and using the`{}` syntax, gcc considers your code to be a said N.C., though it appears to work flawlessly!

Comment: Yeah, I suppose in the general case going from 32 bit to 8 bit will always create a narrowing conversion error. There must be a way to override this behaviour (a static_cast?) and the compiler documentation should have this information. I think it can be shown that taking the sum of N values in the range [0,255] and then dividing the result by N is going to yield a value in the [0,255] range. I think the error is there to make you check the code for possible errors, which in this case I think we're OK.

Answer (score 2):

p.1: Use an explicit cast.

p.2: In general it is not enough. Every time you operate on floating point types you will lose precision. That depends on your operation in respect to your floating point type. To prevent this in your case, you can check for saturation, e.g.:

```
uchar v = (uchar)(value < 255.0 ? value : 255);
```

But I don't think that you will need it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `unsigned` for the accumulator type (assuming you're accumulating fewer than 2^24 values), and `double` for the floating point type (as it's the type of literal decimal values).

Then you're just missing the `static_cast<unsigned char>(rounded_floating_point_value)` to get your floating point rounded results back to the desired type warning-free.

Comment: Thank you for the cast hint!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `unsigned int`

```
cv::Vec3b processing_func(const point&) { ... }

unsigned int acc_r, acc_g, acc_b;
    for (point p: point_set) {
    const cv::Vec3b color = processing_func(p);
    acc_r += color[0]; acc_g += color[1]; acc_b += color[2];
}
```

then for the rounding i would make us of % operator in the following manner

```
cv::Vec3b result_color{acc_r / set_size + acc_r % set_size * 2 / set_size,
                       acc_g / set_size + acc_g % set_size * 2 / set_size,
                       acc_b / set_size + acc_b % set_size * 2 / set_size};
```

notice that `0 <= a % b * 2 < 2b`, so `a % b * 2 / b` is 0 when `a%b < b/2` and 1 when `a%b >= b/2`

Comment: not quite. but otherwise it is mathematically precise, produces the exact value as `(int)roundf(acc_r / (float)set_size` and is about twice as fast (based on my own testing)